# Buscar en multiples input text y mostrar filas automaticas de una tabla? Jquery - ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

bueno en estos momentos estoy que hago un pequeño sistema donde al escribir una palabra en un input text, automaticamente me muestra las filas de una tabla. Ahora aqui esta mi problema...y si yo quiero escribir en 2, 3 a mas input y que cargue automaticamente...no me sale, solo me captura el primer input. Este es mi codigo:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="" id="apellido1">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="" id="apellido2">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="" id="nombre">

<div id="cargar_tabla"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#apellido1').on('keypress', function(){
          var apellido1=$(this).val();
          var apellido2=$('#apellido2').val();
          var nombre=$('#nombre').val();

          $.ajax({
          url: "/Familias/Personas/Tabla",
          type: "post",
          dataType: "json",
          data: {_token: "{{ csrf_token() }}", text: apellido1, text2: apellido2, text3: nombre },
          success: function (response) {
                $("#cargar_tabla").html(response);
          }
        });

      });
  });
</script>
```

Las 2 siguientes variables, si los pongo dentro o fuera de la funcion del primer input igual no sale, ayuda :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo funciona con el primer input porque esta usando el id del primer input para escuchar el `keypress`.  Necesitas crear una clase y escuchar en esa clase.  Algo asi:

```
<input class="form-control nombre" type="text" name="" id="apellido1">
<input class="form-control nombre" type="text" name="" id="apellido2">
<input class="form-control nombre" type="text" name="" id="nombre">

<div id="cargar_tabla"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.nombre').on('keypress', function(){
          var apellido1=$('#apellido1').val();
          var apellido2=$('#apellido2').val();
          var nombre=$('#nombre').val();

          $.ajax({
          url: "/Familias/Personas/Tabla",
          type: "post",
          dataType: "json",
          data: {_token: "{{ csrf_token() }}", text: apellido1, text2: apellido2, text3: nombre },
          success: function (response) {
                $("#cargar_tabla").html(response);
          }
        });

      });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Gracias amigo! Me sirvio!, no sabia muy bien eso del keypress pero con ese dato ya me salio!

Comment: Algo redundante la clase, ya que con la de `form-control` se puede lograr el mismo objetivo

Comment: Normalmente, `form-control` se usa para formatear todo tipo de elementos en formas.  Si OP tiene otros inputs con esa clase podria generar resultados no deseados.  Yo pienso que es mejor crear una clase especifica que se dedique unicamente al objetivo deseado.